# recover removed bluetooth sound device

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth headset and it used to show up in sound settings before I accidentally clicked "turn off" or something like that. Now it won't show up when paired. No joy after reboot and re-pair.

It pairs fine with my ubuntu as well as with my phone, only one is connected at a time. It seems like the "turn off" filtered this device in some ALSA configs but grep returned nothing under /etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by removing all the files in `~/.pulse` except `client.conf`.

Comment: that's definitely one way to do it. I installed blueman and it has options to change the audio profile of a bluetooth device.

Comment: I eventually have to this. blue man has its issues.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In "Audio Settings", you can change the audio profile for your BT device. However, once you set it to "Off", which is what I did, BT audio device no longer shows up in "Audio Settings."

The simple solution is rather simple: [blueman](http://blueman-project.org/). Install via PPA and right click on your audio device and change audio profile back to not off.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, then after I solved this by uncommenting and change the line ControllerMode = dual to **ControllerMode = bredr** of main.conf file. You can open that file using **sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf** and then restart the bluetooth using **sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart** .
you can follow [this](https://youtu.be/fpFiJKHTdFY)